# How to send data to server outside the client class

Tags: java, sockets, client

I am writing a server-client program. It is like a simple console chat room. I use server thread to handle multiple clients. It works well if I put the `Scanner` inside the client constructor.(This part is commented) But, I want to move the `Scanner` part which requests input from user to the `main`. I got `socket close error`.I don't know what the problem is. How can I use `send` function to send data in `main`?

Client:

```
public class GameClient {
private Socket socket;
private String serverIP;
private OutputStreamWriter writer;
private BufferedReader reader;

public GameClient(String host){
    this.serverIP = host;

    try{
        //Connect to server
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 1234);
        writer = new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        //Start a new thread for reading from server
        new Thread(new GameClientReader(socket)).start();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write something: ");
        String str = "";
//          while((str = scanner.nextLine()) != null){
//              writer.write(str);
//              writer.write('\n');
//              writer.flush();
//              System.out.println("Write something: ");
//          }

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Client failed to connect!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void send(JSONObject json){
    try{
        String message = json.toJSONString();
        writer.write(message);
        writer.write('\n');
        writer.flush();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void send(String msg){
    try {
        writer.write(msg);
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    GameClient client = new GameClient("127.0.0.1");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write something: ");
    String str = "";
    while((str = scanner.nextLine()) != null){
        client.send(str);
        System.out.println("Write something: ");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: There is no such error as 'socket close error'. Your question has nothing to do with your title. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close `Socket` in `finally` block of `GameClient` constructor, and then call method `send` which calls `writer.write(msg);` that uses instance of `Socket`